# How to properly compile ParaView for headless offscreen rendering?

Tags: headless, paraview, mesa, off-screen, osmesa

I'm running OpenFOAM on a remote server and basically manage to visualize the results via paraview's `pvserver` [as described here](https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Setting_up_a_ParaView_Server). However upon connection the client yields

> Server DISPLAY not accessible!
>
> Display is not accessible on the server side. Remote rendering will be disabled.

which is basically correct, since the server doesn't run an X server. Performance is of course suboptimal since without remote rendering the entire geometry is transferred (I guess it's almost as bad as directly ssh-copying the files to run purely locally). The server *does* have a simple onboard GPU (c2:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 41) as per `lspci`), using which might be called plan B since at some point I might switch to a server without GPU or an entirely different one. So instead, I had a look at https://kitware.github.io/paraview-docs/latest/cxx/Offscreen.html, and using Arch Linux I obtained [its paraview `PKGBUILD`](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/paraview/) via [`asp checkout paraview`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System#Retrieve_PKGBUILD_source_using_Git) and appended the following switches to its `build() -> cmake` instruction:

```
        -DVTK_OPENGL_HAS_OSMESA=ON \
        -DVTK_USE_X=OFF \
        -DPARAVIEW_USE_QT=OFF \
```

Compilation went without errors (though lots of warnings which I *might* have to check if they are different with and without those switches), yet `pvserver` now SEGFAULTs:

```
$LD_PRELOAD=/usrlib/libGLEW.so pvserver --force-offscreen-rendering
Waiting for client...
Connection URL: cs://xxx:11111
Accepting connection(s): xxx:11111
Client connected.
(  52.668s) [pvserver        ]vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.c:565    ERR| vtkOSOpenGLRenderWindow (0x55f0fa7f4b60): GLEW could not be initialized: Missing GL version

Loguru caught a signal: SIGSEGV
Stack trace:
0       0x7f53ca2c8f80 /usr/bin/../lib/libc.so.6(+0x3cf80) [0x7f53ca2c8f80]
(  52.669s) [pvserver        ]                       :0     FATL| Signal: SIGSEGV
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

`LD_PRELOAD`ing the existing `libGLEW.so` as suggested e.g. [here](https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/issues/268#issuecomment-595177264) did not change things so now I'm stuck... `/usr/lib/libosmesa.so` is also present, as is `libOpenGL.so`, so what am I missing? How can I troubleshoot this properly?

Comment: The correct doc is available here: https://kitware.github.io/paraview-docs/v5.9.0/cxx/Offscreen.html

your build should be fonctionnal though.

Comment: @MathieuWestphal Oh thanks! Hm, so is this more of a problem with my mesa installation then? I'm afraid I don't know how to climb further down this rabbit hole...

Comment: why do you preload libGLEW ?

Comment: @MathieuWestphal It's just a fix suggested at https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/issues/268#issuecomment-595177264, but doesn't change the result either way

Comment: Ok. All I can tell you is that specific setup works perfectly here. How did you build/install osmesa ?

Comment: @MathieuWestphal [`libOSMesa.so` is part of the `extra/mesa`](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/mesa/) package on Arch (or more precisely Manjaro) Linux. I'm maybe a bit lost in X server stuff - does the server need any instance of Xorg e.g.? But I guess I should ask that separately on unix.SE...

Comment: I'm using ArchLinux as well, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using ArchLinux and the folowing is working perfectly:

```
git clone https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview.git --recursive
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -GNinja -DVTK_OPENGL_HAS_OSMESA=ON  -DVTK_USE_X=OFF -DPARAVIEW_USE_QT=OFF ../paraview
ninja
./bin/pvserver
```

then connecting from an actual ParaView and rendering something on the server works perfectly.

Comment: Oh great, I'll give this a shot, thank you :)

Comment: It works, thank you very much! I'll try and create an adequate `PKGBUILD` file later on. Note to self since I'm still using 5.8.1: `git worktree add v5.8.1 v5.8.1; cd v5.8.1; git submodule update --init --recursive` (of course instead of `worktree` a detached `checkout` would work just as well)

Comment: Are there any prerequisites?  Following these steps on Ubuntu 20.04, `cmake` failed with "Could not find the OSMesa external dependency".

Comment: install osmesa I suppose ?